# How to pass a object into directive controller in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive called dealEngine which has template and controller and is working fine.

however as you can see I'm trying to collect the object from attribute and pass it into my controller! so far I either get `undefined` or `"string"`.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app')
        .directive('dealEngine', dealEngine)
        .controller("dealEngineCtrl", dealEngineCtrl);

    dealEngine.$inject = ['$state'];
    function dealEngine($state) {

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: 'true',
            cache:'false',
            controller: 'dealEngineCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'directives/deal/deal.html',
            scope:{
                "deal":"="
            }
        };

    }
    dealEngineCtrl.$inject = ['$scope','$attrs', '$element'];
    function dealEngineCtrl($scope, $attrs, $element) {
        console.log($attrs.deal); //this returns "vm.deal" string!!!
        console.log($scope.deal); //this returns undefined!!!
    }
})();
```

Comment: is `vm.deal` being set in asynchronous callback like through $http? If so would make sense it is undefined when directive first gets compiled. What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: YOU ARE RIGHT! :), I used $scope.$watch and it works!